# Numpy: Alternative ways to construct a matrix of points given the matrix of each coordinate separately

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, coordinates

Let x, y, z be matrix representations, so that (x[i, j], y[i, j], z[i, j]) corresponds to a certain point.

Instead of having 3 variables we want to have just one variable (Points) where "Points[i,j]=(x[i,j],y[i,j],z[i,j])" and "Points[i,j,0]=x[i,j]"

Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 1],
              [2, 2]])
y = np.array([[1, 2],
              [1, 2]])
z = np.array([[3, 4],
              [5, 6]])
Points = np.array([[ [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 4] ],
                     [2, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6] ]])
```

Currently I have thought of some solutions:

1st Solution:

```
from itertools import izip
Temp_List=[]
for xi, yi, zi in izip(x, y, z):
    Temp_List.append([(xij, yij, zij) for xij, yij, zij in izip(xi, yi, zi)])
Points=np.array(Temp_List)
```

I know that unpacking a tuple to pack it again is not very smart, but is 
for the sake of making it more readable and prepare the next solution

2nd Solution: # one-liner

```
from itertools import izip
Points=np.array([zip(xi, yi, zi) for xi, yi, zi in izip(x,y,z)])
```

I really like this option. However in this solution I'm concerned about readability. Maybe it's just me but I feel that it is not that obvious that the list comprehension generates something similar to Points in the Example. Unless you are familiarized with the difference between izip and zip.

It's obvious another solution is using indexes to iterate over the elements x, y and z like in other languages ( for i in xrange(...) : for j in xrange(...): do stuff ... )

Concluding: 
Is there another way of generating the Points variable from x,y,z using a numpy function ( or not) that improves either Readability, Memory consumption or performance ?

Comment: Simply use : `np.dstack((x,y,z))`?

Comment: The old `dstack`, `hstack` and `vstack` functions are now deprecated in favor of `stack`. In this case `np.stack([x, y, z], axis=2)`

Comment: Thanks both answers are exactly what I was looking for! I'm not very familiar with numpy yet. Also I have run a few tests and for small matrices the performance is about the same, however when using bigger matrices np.stack overwhelms the other solutions. From what I have read in other questions it should also be more memory efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's `stack` function:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
])

y = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2],
])

z = np.array([
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
])


points = np.stack([x, y, z], axis=2)
```

`stack` with the `axis` keyword supersedes the old `vstack`, `hstack` and `dstack` functions, which are now deprecated.